# NSXMLParser Asynch -How do I properly Release?

Tags: iphone, ios, asynchronous, nsxmlparser

OK. I'm using NSXMLParser like so:

```
myParser = [[[BMLT_Parser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:uri]] retain];
[myParser setDelegate:self];
[myParser performSelectorInBackground:@selector(parse) withObject:nil];
```

I have my own subclass in order to do things like have a memory pool and some instance data. Basically, it's OK to think of BMLT_Parser as the same as NSXMLParser.

Note that I am calling it asynchronously, so there's no simple deallocation after a synchronous call.

What I have done, is declare the following delegate function:

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser  ///< The parser in question
{
    [myParser release];
    myParser = nil;
}
```

myParser is an instance variable of the parser. Basically, myParser == parser in the callback.

Now, the problem is that Instruments tells me that the parser is leaking. Parsers leak badly, because they pack a lot of luggage.

How else should I dealloc asych parsers? I strongly suspect that I simply need to be directed to an "M", so that I can "RTFM".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myParser = [[[BMLT_Parser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:uri]] retain];
```

In the above code, u r firstly  allocating memory for myParser by alloc, and again u r  retaining .Here, u r doing wrong as u should retain only when u have take ownership of an object.But through alloc u will get ownership of the object"myParser".
And when u have used the object, u need to release that.
you should do like something this..

```
myParser = [[BMLT_Parser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:uri]];
[myParser setDelegate:self];
[myParser performSelectorInBackground:@selector(parse) withObject:nil];
[myParser release];
```

Again, in the delegate definition, you r firstly releasing the object then setting that to nil.This is quite meaningless ,as if u don't have memory for any object, how can we set any value to that. write something like this..

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser  ///< The parser in question
    {
    if(_myParser)
        {
          [_myParser release];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why you're doing that in the callback. I'll think on it some more. On another note, Instruments in Xcode 4.1/Lion completely blows chunks. I have to force quit it about 4 times out of 5.

Comment: there is no need to have ownership of the object "myParser".

Comment: OK. I got it. This wasn't 100% of my problem, but it was 95% of it.